# Comparing Two Pandas Dataframes and Creating a List of Values

Tags: list, python-3.x, dataframe

I have 2 `pandas dataframes`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Model': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Color': ['Orange', 'Red', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Pink']})

Color   Model
Orange   1
Red      2
Black    3
Purple   4
Pink     5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Orange', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Black', 'Indigo'], 'Drink': ['Soda', 'Juice', 'Water', 'Soda', 'Lemonade'], 'Model': [1,1,4,6,8]})


Color   Drink   Model
Orange  Soda      1
Green   Juice     1
Purple  Water     4
Black   Soda      6
Indigo  Lemonade  8
```

I am trying to get create a `list` of Drinks from `df2` whose Color and Model match the Color and Model from `df1`. For the above example the output should be:

`['Soda', 'Water']`

How would I accomplish this? I've tried:

```
drinks = []
for x in df1.Model:
    for y in df2.Model:
        for j in df1.Color:
            for k in df2.Color:
                if x == y and j == k:
                    drinks.append(df2.loc[df2['Model'] == x, 'Drink'].iloc[0])
```

which returns:

`['Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Water', 'Water', 'Water']`

I think I'm close but not sure how to get rid of the repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out with the following:

```
df3 = df2.loc[(df2['Color'].isin(list(df1.Color))) & df2.Model.isin(list(df1.Model))]

list(df3.Drink)
```

Output:

```
['Soda', 'Water']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your duplicated list contains all needed values, you can convert it to `set()`=)

```
lst=['Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Soda', 'Water', 'Water', 'Water']
unique_list=list(set(lst))
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that though my actual data set is vastly larger than the example and processing it the way I've written it is far too inefficient